# How to decode jsonpickle data in angular typescript file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jsonpickle

I'm creating an hobby application where Angular is front-end and Python is acting as back-end.
A component in Angular is sending HTTP GET to Python upon which python responds with a jsonpickled object.

**I wish to unpickle (decode) the jsonpickled object received in HTTP RESPONSE.**
The unpickle (decode) would happen in Angular's component.ts file where the HTTP REPSONSE object is received.

Followed the instructions as per example files here, but it is not working: https://github.com/cuthbertLab/jsonpickleJS (under tests directory there's testUnpickle.html file which I had used as reference but the part within script tags just doesn't execute).

Below is the code in Angular's component.ts file:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/restaurants/' + this.id
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(
      response => 
      {
        this.name = response['name'];
        this.location = response['location'];
        this.photos = response['photos']; // this is the jsonpickled object, I want to unpickle it so as to get a File Object.
        console.log(response)
      }
    )
  }
```

Below is snip from component.html file:

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/jsonpickleJS-master/build/jsonpickle.min.js"
  data-main= "jsonpickleJS/main"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    picfileobj = jsonpickle.decode(photos)
    console.log("getting decoded file for pic")
    console.log(picfileobj)
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Able to decode the jsonpickle object received in HTTP RESPONSE using below.

1. Download the jsonpickle js files from https://github.com/cuthbertLab/jsonpickleJS
2. Import in angular.json (jsonpickle.min.js)
3. Declare var jsonpickle in your xyz.component.ts file:
4. Use the jsonpickle.decode(jsonpickled_object) method to get the original file object.